# CMake OpenCV Cannot Specify Link Libraries

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cmake

I am trying to run an OpenCV program written in C++ on Ubuntu. I followed [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) tutorial to install OpenCV on my system.

I then followed [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html) tutorial to run my code with the following Cmake commands as specified in the tutorial:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( PedestrianDetection )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( PedestrianDetection PedestrianDetection.cpp )
target_link_libraries(  ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

However, Cmake gives me the following output:

```
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "opencv_videostab" which is not
  built by this project.
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to link the libraries?

By the way, I am using OpenCV2.4.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from the [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries)

> target_link_libraries: Link a target to given libraries.
>
> target_link_libraries(`<target>` [item1 [item2 [...]]]
>                           [[debug|optimized|general] `<item>`] ...)
>
> Specify libraries or flags to use when linking a given target. The
>   named  must have been created in the current directory by a
>   command such as add_executable or add_library. The remaining arguments
>   specify library names or flags.

try instead

```
target_link_libraries(PedestrianDetection ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Comment: Hi, I'm stuck here too but then I'm using OpenCV with Python and not C++ ... and I'm not quite sure that target_link_libraries happens to be the same as above in this case. But I can't find any information regarding this either. Would you happen to know of anything that would help?

Comment: @Raaj Sorry, I'm not really familiar with using cmake on python. I'd suggest creating a new question.