# Cmake OpenCV Can not specify link libraries

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

i wanted to run this c++/OpenCV code that i found online:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html

I have a problem with CMake, it returned this error:

*CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "SURF_Homography" which is not
  built by this project.*

I searched on the web the solution, and i found this

[CMake OpenCV Cannot Specify Link Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23124655/cmake-opencv-cannot-specify-link-libraries)

but i can't understand why mine don't work because it looks like the same, this is my CMakeLists file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( SURF_Homography )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( SURF_Homography.cpp SURF_Homography.cpp )
target_link_libraries( SURF_Homography ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

hope you can help me
thanks 
Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `add_executable` line:

```
add_executable( SURF_Homography SURF_Homography.cpp )
```

Otherwise, the target you are specifying in the `target_link_libraries` line won't exist :)